# Unable to sculpt object with Subdivision Surface modifier

Tags: eevee-render-engine, sculpting, subdivision-surface

I have used a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and a *Mirror* modifier to create my object. I was able to create a body of the object, make a robe and boots, but I wasn't able to sculpt the face.

[image: screenshot of the model]

I have tried restarting Blender, used Dyntopo, strengthening my brush, but nothing is working. Every time I use the sculpting tool it has no effect on the object.

Is it possible that Blender is not able to sculpt an object once a subdivision surface modifier has been used or am I missing a step?

Here is the zip package of the blend file I am sculpting at the moment:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nph6Jx0vx5kjgM3wemL0PDCnW-sSuxpf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sculpting is working on real geometry by moving vertices. Your _Mirror_ and 
 _Subdivision Surface_ modifier are only creating temporary, virtual meshes that are subject to change whenever you change the axis of mirroring or the levels of subdivisions. So the sculpting information cannot be stored in the vertices because they do not really exist in the mesh. Almost all modifiers have to be applied if you want to work with the mesh generated by them. An exception is the _Multires_ modifier which exactly does this - providing a virtual mesh for sculpting to have multiple levels of subdivision.

Comment: How do I apply all the modifiers and how do I use the Multires modifier to provide a virtual mesh? When I tried to use the Multires modifier it only cuts the object in half and I still cannot sculpt it.

Comment: It's not cutting the object in half, it disables your _Mirror_ modifier - because as I said, the modifier does not provide "real" geometry which can be sculpted. To apply a modifier you have to be in _Object Mode_ and then hover over a modifier and press Ctrl-A to apply it. Or to apply all modifiers at once, press Ctrl+A in the _3D Viewport_ and choose _Visual Geometry to Mesh_. But beware, this way all changes made by modifiers are permanent and cannot be changed anymore.

Comment: Just putting the _Multires_ modifier on the object alone does not give you a hi res mesh to sculpt. It lets you add subdivisions which you switch between depending on what mode you choose, so e.g. low res for general sculpting, hi res for finer details and you can also choose which resolution shall be visible in the _3D Viewport_ when in _Object Mode_ and which should be used for rendering. But I'm not gonna give you a complete tutorial on how to use the _Multires_ modifier for sculpting. There are tutorials on sculpting out there. For specific questions on it better ask a new question here.

Comment: It worked! I chose Visual Geometry to Mesh in the Object mode and I am now able to sculpt the object! Thank you so much for your help!